# convert code from perl to python for table handling

Tags: python, perl

I have this code in perl that allows me to create a list of 8 to 1 and to create a numbering table.
the array is filled by adding to the list data (i.e. 8 to 1) before a "suffix" which is 1. i.e. inside the array we will have numrotation `[1.8, 1.7, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1]`. then fill the array with the values of `1 ..15` and `15.1 15.2 15.3` and `16..32`

I would like to know which function can replace the push functions. I put you the code in perl and my test in python which did not :
code in perl :

```
for ( reverse( 1 .. 8 ) ) { push @Numerotation, '1.' . $_ }         push
@Numerotation, ( 1 .. 15, 15.1, 15.2, 15.3, 16 .. 31, 34 .. 45 );
```

code in python (does not work) :

```
import numpy as np 

lst = list(range(1,8+1)) 
lst.reverse() 
print(lst) 
numerotation= np.array()

for i in lst :      
    d=1.+i
    numerotation.append(d) 

print(numerotation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using numpy you can't do an append directly on the array like you can with regular Python lists. Instead you need to use the class function [`append()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html). Also since [`np.array()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array) requires input you need to use `np.empty(0)` to create an empty array.

```
import numpy as np

lst = list(range(1, 8+1))
lst.reverse()
print(lst)
numerotation = np.empty(0)

for i in lst :
    d = "1." + str(i)
    numerotation = np.append(numerotation, d)

print(numerotation)
```

In your Perl code you create the floats as strings so I left them that way in this example. To make them numbers you need to convert them using `float(d)`.

Here is another approach that uses a regular Python list and then creates a numpy array from it.

```
import numpy as np

lst = list(range(1, 8+1))
lst.reverse()
print(lst)
numbers = ["1." + str(i) for i in lst]

numerotation = np.array(numbers)

print(numerotation)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, it seems to work, just have to convert to float